# How to make three dotted line?

Tags: graphs

How do I make a 3 dotted line connecting 2 vertices. Like this image
[image]

Answer (score 5):

here you have two solutions, the first one uses `\dots` and the second draws three independent dots where you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycircle/.style={circle, draw, inner sep=2pt},
    mydot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=.5pt}]

\node[mycircle] (a1) {} ;
\node[mycircle, right=3cm of a1] (a2) {};
\node[mycircle, below=2cm of a1] (b1) {};
\node[mycircle, right=5mm of b1] (b2) {};
\node[mycircle, right=3cm of b2] (b3) {};
\draw[ultra thick] (a1)--(b1) (a1)--(b2) (a2)--(b3);
\path (a1) -- node {\dots} (a2);
\path (b2)-- node[mydot, pos=.333] {} node[mydot] {} node[mydot, pos=.666] {}(b3);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]